# Study a math course on my own, suggestions?

Tags: self-learning

I would like to study some math on my own. I am currently studying my second semester at a university and I have too much freetime so I would like to study something on my own, but I can't decide what to study.
I have finished courses in: calculus in one and several variables, mechanics for engineers and a course that dealt with some number theory and proofs. 
I am currently taking linear algebra and probability theory.

So, I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions of what I could study on my own and if so, is there a book you would recommend?

Comment: Depends what your university already offers. I'd recommend something it doesn't.

Comment: An important question too : What part of maths do you like?

Comment: Do you feel comfortable with mathematical proofs?  Are you being shown proofs and asked to prove statements yourself in your linear algebra course?  If not, since proofs are a huge part of mathematics, I recommend you find a text on elementary proof writing and familiarize yourself with some standard elementary proof techniques.  Such a text would also have exercises where you can prove statements on your own.

Comment: I really enjoyed the calculus courses and I like the ones I study now. But since I haven't studied that much yet I don't really now what I would like to study.       My university doesn't offer that many courses, it's not a big university.

Comment: You might enjoy studying complex analysis. If you're self studying, I would go with a less rigorous approach to get you started.

Comment: I'm being shown a lot of proofs in linear algebra, but so far I haven't had to do any on my own. I don't feel too comfortable doing proofs on my own. I took a course were we did a lot of them and we had to do some ourselves, but that was the first course I took and I felt really insecure

Comment: @Eva That's why I think reviewing a text on elementary proof techniques would help.  It would review logic first, and then show you the standard elementary techniques that you no doubt come across often.  I think spending time on this will help you feel more secure about not only understanding proofs, but writing them on your own without any help, too.

Comment: I think you're right. I will probably have to do a lot of proofs in future courses so it would be a good idea to learn more and feel confident about writing proofs.            Is there a book or author you could recommend?

Comment: @Eva Check the document linked below out.  If you think it is helpful and kind of an easy read, then you should check the author's book out (it's on amazon; titled Bridge to Abstract Mathematics: Mathematical proofs and structures.  http://www.mhhe.com/math/advmath/rosen/r5/student/data/proofwriting.pdf

Comment: In your place I would freely go through a lot of results in form of theorems  Lemmas etc. out of several well written books. Then it would be  " why should that be so?" in some cases, an area to probe details of connecting arguments ..

Answer (score 0):

You could make a start into analysis and abstract algebra. "Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus" is a very good book for an introduction into analysis written by Ross. I don't know a good book for an introduction into abstract algebra but there are plenty. You could start with "group theory".

Good Luck!

Added:
A good introduction into 'real' mathematics is: "Reading, Writing, and Proving: A Closer Look at MathematicsA textbook by Pamela Gorkin & Ulrich Daepp" which starts with basic notions of: what is a set, a bijection, how do you proof something by induction etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you study something related to engineering I would recommend you to start a course on harmonic analysis (also known as Fourier analysis). At this moment I am reading a book which contains the very basic knowledge in this area along with a whole chapter about measure theory, which I assume you are not familiar with from what you've said, but you'll need the basics (which are not hard) to be able to study this area. The book reference is:

C. S. Rees, S. M. Shah, C. V. Stanojevic, *Theory and Applications of Fourier Analysis*.